# Dimension of a scheme $X$ at a closed point $x$ and dimension of its local ring.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, krull-dimension, local-rings

The dimension of an irreducible scheme $X$ at $x$, dim$_x(X)$ is defined as the smallest dimension among its open neighbourhoods and the dimension of its local ring dim$(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ is just the Krull dimension.

There are many properties of those two dimensions, as well as the Krull dimension of a scheme dim$X$, and their relationships. For example, dim$X$=sup$_x$ dim$_x(X)$=dim$(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ for closed points $x$.

I am wondering

(1) if it is true that dim$_x(X)$=dim$(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ for a closed point $x$?

(2) And how to prove $\dim _ x(X) \geq \dim (\mathcal{O}_{X, x})$ in general? (I guess it is true...)

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: 1. Please use `\dim` inside math mode to format $\dim$ instead of leaving "dim" in plain text outside math mode. 2. Hint: do you know what the prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ correspond to?

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for your suggestion. I am not really sure...

Comment: @jingyey the correspondence to which KReiser alludes is that primes of $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ correspond to irreducible subvarieties that pass through $x$. Can you see how this relates the two notions of dimension quite intimately?

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks for your comments! It seems to me that your correspondence proves the result that $\text{codim} (x, X) = \dim (\mathcal{O}_{X, x})$, for a closed point $x$. But by definition, $\text{codim} (x, X)$ looks different from $\dim_x(X)$ in any textbooks... am i right?

Comment: @jingyey I don't think that's quite right. Make sure you have all of your inclusions in the right direction.

Comment: @TabesBridges Sorry, which part do you think is not quite right? The definition of  $\text{codim} (x, X) $ is using the sup length of chains of irreducible closed schemes beginning with x, but the definition of $\dim (\mathcal{O}_{X, x})$ is very different, as in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0055

Comment: @jingyey To make sure we're speaking of the same concepts: if I have a scheme $X$ of pure dimension $3$, then $\dim(\mathcal O_{X,x}) = 3$ for all $x \in X$, correct? But $\operatorname{codim}(x,X)$ can be $0,1,2,$ (for $x$ the generic point of $X$ or some subvariety) or $3$ (for $x$ closed). And I think $\dim_x(X) = 3$ for all $x \in X$ here. And the link to The Stacks Project doesn't take me to the definition of $\dim(\mathcal O_X,x)$, but shouldn't it be something like...

Comment: ... "supremum of the lengths of all possible chains of primes containing the ideal of $x$"? And what about your definition of $\operatorname{codim}_x(X)$?

Comment: @TabesBridges Sorry, your second-to-last post contains an error - $\dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ depends on $x$. For instance if $x$ is the generic point of an integral scheme, then $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=K(X)$, a field, which is of dimension zero as a ring. The OP's claim that $\dim(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})=\operatorname{codim}(x,X)$ is almost correct, except one should take the local codimension. At this point I'm probably on the hook for writing an answer myself, which I was sort of trying to avoid...

Comment: @KReiser thank you! For whatever reason I have always found generic points confusing in practice, despite being perfectly aware in the abstract of things like "localizing at the generic point produces the function field."